# AdobeCreativeSDK : 'SDK Version Mismatch', reason: 'No CreativeSDKFoundation version found'

Tags: ios, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I've to Integrate **AviarySDK** which is known as **AdobeCreativeSDK**.
I've added `AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation` and `AdobeCreativeSDKImage` and other frameworks related to it. Also add some linker flags. and refer Following links.
I'm working with **XCode 6.1.**.

1. https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageediting/index.html
2. https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202903359-Migrating-from-the-Aviary-SDK-to-the-Adobe-Creative-SDK-Beta

And here is my code.

```
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation/AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.h>
#import <AdobeCreativeSDKImage/AdobeCreativeSDKImage.h>
```

added `AdobeUXImageEditorViewControllerDelegate`

```
[[AdobeUXAuthManager sharedManager]setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID:@"MyKey" withClientSecret:@"MySecret"];
AVYPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AVYPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];

#pragma mark - AdobeCreativeSDK Delegates
- (void)photoEditor:(AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)editor finishedWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    //Got Image.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)photoEditorCanceled:(AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)editor
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But I got some unknown Error as below.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SDK Version Mismatch', reason: 'No CreativeSDKFoundation version found'

Please check below Screenshot.

[image]

I'm missing something? Help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the issue. You have to add bundle resource for your each Framework under **Build Phases ▸ Copy Bundle Resource**  you have to add manually. Bundle Resource is exist under **AdobeCreativeSDKImage.framework ▸ Versions ▸ A ▸ Resources** . Follow same steps for all framework you've added to your project.

Comment: You also need the bundle from the AdobeCreativeSDKCore.framework.